# How to load two mo files for gettext localization

Tags: php, mysql, gettext

I am trying to solve this to load two mo file. 
I have two mo files both have different msgid and msgstr.

My folder structure is as below.
local/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/lang.mo
local/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/brand.mo

Following code I am using to load mo file.

```
define('PROJECT_DIR', realpath('./'));
define('LOCALE_DIR', PROJECT_DIR .'/locale');
define('DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US');
$encoding = 'UTF-8';
$locale = (isset($_SESSION['lang']))? $_SESSION['lang'] : DEFAULT_LOCALE;
// gettext setup
T_setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
// Set the text domain as 'messages'
$our_domain = 'lang';
T_bindtextdomain($our_domain, LOCALE_DIR);
T_bind_textdomain_codeset($our_domain, $encoding);
T_textdomain($our_domain);
```

How can I add here one more mo file

Comment: When I used Gettext in PHP I used to associate one .po/.mo pair with one or more scripts, not the opposite. You can however switch .mo files but I don't remember the exact function to do it, I'll look into it and come back.

Comment: With one mo file all is working fine. But here i have multiple mo with different strings i want load all mo files once .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `bindtextdomain` and `textdomain` functions once again to set a new translations file as the default resource.

A good way to simplify it would be to create the utilitary function let's say `selectTrFile($filename)` which would make it look like this :

```
function selectTrFile($trFile) {
    bindtextdomain($trFile, TRANSLATION_BASE_DIR); // The constant being the path of you translations file directory
    textdomain($trFile);
}

// Now set the first file

selectTrFile('default');

// Do your stuff with this translations file

selectTrFile('anotherTranslationsResource');

// Have fun with it
```

You can even make it quicker by wrapping the function above in another that switches automatically the file for you.

```
function _f($msgid, $trFile){ // called _f to make it very short to type
    selectTrFile($trFile); // Switch the translations file
    return _($msgid); // Return the translated string
}

// Then wrap your translations filenames in short variables
$f1 = 'lang';
$f2 = 'brand';

// now you can translate Strings easily from one file or another.
_f("to be translated in file 'lang'", $f1);
_f("to be translated in file 'brand'", $f2);
```

If what you do not know in which file the translation is, you can use this function instead of `_f($msgid, $trFile);`

```
function _f($msgid){

     selectTrFile('lang'); // or set a variable containing the filename and use it

     $msgstr = _($msgid);

     if($msgstr == $msgid){ // if the Strings are equals it means that there was no match in the first file
         selectTrFile('brand'); // or set a variable containing the second filename and use it
         $msgstr = _$(msgid);
     }

     return $msgstr;
 }
```

The problem with this last one is that it may slow down a lot the process, I don't know at what point. You could optimize it by not changing to `'lang'` every time, looking what is the actual one if the String was not translated or something like this.

**Edit**

I don't think you can have multiples translations resources loaded at once. It would be too dangerous for msgid's conflicts. You would be better of making one bigger .mo file than loading multiple ones.

This is the reason why msgfmt makes sure that there are no conflicting msgids at compile time. Do not be afraid of very large .po/.mo files. Mo is a compiled and very fast format.

The problem that could appear now is having a very clumsy .po file. To avoid it, the best way is to separate the file in sections.

There are two ways of separating the sections, either by file or subjet. If you plan on having the same translations in multiple files (which should happen very rarely if you use your includes properly), you can separate by subject.

The usual way is to separate by file and add in a comment where the string is from.

```
##
# File : /your/php/file.php
##
msgid "first String in file.php"
msgstr "first translation in file.php
.
.
.
##
# File : your/other/file.php
##
msgid "other translation"
msgstr "and then you go on"
```

So the point is that you should never need to access multiple .mo files from a single .php file if you follow properly the guidelines.

See [here (The format of PO files)](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#PO-Files) for more informations.

Comment: Will your answer allow to use two .mo files together? will it allow to get translation from two files.

Comment: Yes but not simultaneously. You will have to call the function every time you want to fetch the translation from another file. I will edit again to explain better.

Comment: I understand this. But the requirement is to keep some id in separate file. There will be no repeated ids in both files. I am received two mo with different ids. And need to use translation from both in same page. In any case if its possible to achieve please suggest me.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to categorise your strings into different *domains* and *categories*:

```
locale/
    en/                    <-- language
       LC_MESSAGES/        <-- category
           messages.mo     <-- domain
           brands.mo       <-- domain
```

You bind your different domains to locale directories to tell gettext which domain can be found where. You then select a default domain, which is used when you call `_('Foo')`. You then use more specialised functions to switch domains or categories:

```
_('Foo')                                  // LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
dgettext('brands', 'Foo')                 // LC_MESSAGES/brands.mo
dcgettext('brands', 'Foo', LC_MONETARY)   // LC_MONETARY/brands.mo
```

The idea is to categorise your strings inside your source code.